# How to successfully run Perl script with setuid() when used as cgi-bin?

Tags: perl, apache, cgi-bin, setuid, suexec

I have a Perl script that is called either via Apache or on the command-line.

For testing purposes, I pass it the username I want the Perl script to operate with, and use `POSIX::setuid` to set the `uid`.

If I run the script from the command line, then the `uid` is set properly:

```
use CGI::Pretty qw/:standard/;
use POSIX qw(setuid getuid);

...
my ($pwName, $pwCode, $pwUid, $pwGid, $pwQuota, $pwComment, 
    $pwGcos, $pwHome, $pwLogprog) = getpwnam($username);

if ((defined $pwUid) && (getuid() == $pwUid)) {
    setuid($pwUid);
    print header;
    print Dumper $<;
}
else {
    print header(-status => 401);
    print "Could not setuid to correct uid (currently: )".getuid()."\n";
}
```

The command-line output shows the correct `uid` of the specified `$username`, instead of the `uid` of the test account that started running the script.

If I call the script via Apache, then the `uid` remains set to the id of the `apache` user, and never changes.

I don't believe I can use `suExec` here, because, after reading the documentation:

1. I can't put a copy of this script into `http://www.example.com/~username` for every `$username`. The script needs to run from one location, and I need to specify the `uid` from within the script.
2. I need to have the script run as the specified username at runtime, and not as a single username specified once in a virtual host directive in an Apache configuration file. Changing this configuration file and restarting Apache every time a new user runs this script is not realistic.

How do I get a Perl script running as a cgi-bin to change the `uid` correctly, when using `setuid()`?

Comment: Your commandline user probably has the rights to change its UID, your webserver-user probably does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can `setuid` to an arbitrary uid is to run as root.[1]

I don't know about you, but the idea of a CGI program running as root gives me nightmares.

What is this code supposed to actually do after changing uid?  Perhaps there's a way to accomplish this without having to `setuid`?

[1] Depending on your code and its security model, you may be able to collect the user's password and use `su`/`sudo`[2] to run a separate command-line program to run the actual operations outside of the web server environment, but `su`/`sudo` are able to do this because they're suid root and it would still open up most/all of the issues associated with running CGI code as root anyhow.  Even if you filter out root as an invalid username, being able to masquerade as any arbitrary user opens up plenty of opportunities for abuse.

[2] `sudo` could even be configured to allow it without requiring a password, but there be dragons down that path.  Be sure you know what you're doing if you attempt it, lest you give your users free reign to impersonate each other at will.

Comment: This cgi-bin is used with an Ajax call. The script should run as the specified user, to limit that user's access to a listing of his or her files on a file system accessible to the web server.

Comment: I think I will have to split out the code I am using to provide the directory listing, and then filter results based on the uid of the provided username.

Comment: @Alex - the latter (have CGI filter out results based on user ID) is actually the best solution for this problem.