# Accessing user files from a perl webserver

Tags: linux, perl

I have a perl server which needs the ability to read user's files and data, and write to them. The users are authenticated via LDAP, so I can verify passwords and learn their home directory.

From here I need some way for this webserver (running as `www-data`) to access their files. I've thought about running every command through `su/sudo` but that's really not optimal when I just need to open/write/close/glob files in their home directories.

Is there standard practice for this? I haven't been able to turn up anything so far.

Notes

- I want the files in their home directory, as the users will be SSHing in and running other commands on them that won't be available via the web
- The web connection is made over HTTPS of course.

**Related**

- [How to successfully run Perl script with setuid() when used as cgi-bin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991001/how-to-successfully-run-perl-script-with-setuid-when-used-as-cgi-bin)

Comment: I would write actions to database or file and use root crontab job to do actual changes on user files.

Comment: Interesting. That's certainly one solution but we're looking for more real-time interaction than that. We will have user credentials passed to us, it seems strange that it wouldn't be possible to impersonate a user for the purposes of these interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to reconsider your architecture.   This sounds like a job for virtual hosts in an ISP-like configuration.

First, read "Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting" page in the [Apache VirtualHost documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).  Then read about how to [run each virtual host as a different user](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/httpd-itk/)

Under this approach you would have a vhost for each user running as `$user.example.com`; when Apache forks off a worker for the vhost, the fork runs suid as the appropriate user.  Then you set up `docroot` and `scriptalias` for the vhost which point to the site code.

Long story short, it's probably better to use Apache's (well-tested and well-documented) features for managing user identity than it is to do it in Perl or whip up your own suid wrapper.  It's notoriously difficult to get it right.

Comment: Well, that's a very interesting solution. Thank you! Marking this as the answer since it solves the problem as described, though I'm not sure I'm going to implement this for a few reasons outside of my control. Agreed, I'd really rather have someone else's code handle this sort of thing and suid and my own perl.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Apache? This sounds like a job for [WebDAV](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html).

The trouble is that your web server is running as www-data. By design, it won't be able to change the owner of any file. Some other privileged process will need to change ownership on the webserver's behalf.

You could write a minimal set UID script to handle changing the ownership of files and deleting them, but this path is fraught with peril (especially if you've never written a setUID program before.)

Comment: Yes, I have used setUID before, but never for anything so benign :P. That may indeed be the best solution. I had wanted to avoid that if it was at all an option but now that you've mentioned it, it may be the best option. I haven't used webDAV outside of dav2fs on linux, could you elaborate on how that solution to my problem might work?